# Postgres.app: cannot find my config and data dir

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-mavericks

I have Postgres.app installed on my Mac (Mavericks). Everything is fine, but I cannot locale the data and config directory.

If I write in psql `SHOW data_directory;` the result is

```
/Users/scrivoaroby/Library/Application Support/Postgres93/var
```

But I cannot find this dir with finder!!! I have Application Support but no Postgres93 directory inside.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If Mavericks says it's there then tell Mavericks to show it. 
Still in terminal, cd into that directory and then write

```
open .
```

That should open the directory in a new finder window.
(I suspect it's a hidden directory.)